# printing application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am in the process of developing a printing application for iPhone. Printing happens through
a dedicated remote server, I just need to send the to be printed documents to this server.

I am facing problems in accessing the documents spread across various apps. I have registered for a good number of file-types. With this approach, only apps which have implemented document interaction will show my app in their "open-in" option (ex safari, mail). But what about rest of the files in apps which do not implement the document interaction controller ? (like photos in the default photos app, documents in iBooks etc)

This limitation seriously hinders the purpose of my app.

What is the best way to let every body (I mean every app having printable documents in the device) know that my app is capable of handling print requests ? How to I hook into their action sheets etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats simply not possible, you can't hook into other apps from within your sandbox and you can't get out of it unless you don't want to be in the App Store. All you can do is to write the creators of these Apps a nice mail and encourage them to use the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, in case of Apple the address would be [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Oh, that disappointing :-( Anyways, thanks for the quick answer.